# Translation of "allegedly"

Tags: traducción

This word is used in the news, I need a Spanish translation, preferably one word translation.

My only research was google translate: https://translate.google.com.ar/#en/es/allegedly
it translates as "**pretendidamente**", as an argentinian speaker I've never heard or read that word in the news, I don't like that translation.

[Example](http://jalopnik.com/a-philly-tow-truck-company-is-allegedly-setting-traps-t-1785705852):  A Philly Tow Truck Company Is Allegedly Setting Traps To Impound Cars

Comment: Hello Santropedro. As you may have already read in [ask], in [spanish.se] we do require some previous research on the questions you ask. So please, could you [edit] to indicate what your thoughts are regarding this translation? Also, do not just include links, but make your post self-contained, copying the relevant things that these pages may have. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common word used in the news to convey that meaning is "**presuntamente**"

Your headline would be translated like:

> Compañía de grúas de Philadelphia **presuntamente** coloca trampas para confiscar carros/coches

Comment: En el periodismo a veces también se usa *habría* como "reportedly." E.g., la compañía tal y tal habría puesto trampas...